# How do I break this array into sub-array(at continuous position) of similar type of alphabets

Tags: java, arrays

For eg., 
the input array is :

```
String array = {"0","0","0","K","K","B","P","P","P","Z",
                "Z","D","D","E","E","F","N","O","O}
```

Output:

```
first sub-array = {"O,O,O"}
second sub-array = {"K","K"}
third sub-array = {"O","O"}
```

Comment: Define programming language

Comment: It is not clear. Can you explain the question briefly?

Comment: @AksenP it's JAVA . You can provide the language in any language.

Comment: What is the condition to get that specific three sub-arrays?

Comment: It should be `String[] array`.

Comment: @Mei I have an input of array and I want the output as I have described above. One sub-array will constitute the elements that are continuously allocated in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using stack for that checkout below code for that.

```
String data[] = { "0", "0", "0", "K", "K", "B", "P", "P", "P", "Z", "Z", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "N" };
// a = ['0','0','0','K','K','P','P','P','Z']

Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
String prevValue = data[0];

for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].equals(data[i - 1])) {
        prevValue = prevValue + data[i];
    } else {
        stack.push(prevValue);
        prevValue = data[i];
    }
}
stack.push(prevValue);
System.out.println(stack);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't know how many different characters you're looking for one possible solution would be using a Map:

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();  
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){  
 if(map.containsKey(array[i])  
  map.get(array[i]).add(array[i]);  
 else  
  map.put(array[i],array[i]);
}
```

However, personally I think what you're asking can be simplified with a Parameter style approach. This is, instead of storing each ocurrence of each string pattern you're looking for, you simply store a counter. So, and still assuming that you don't know how many distinct patterns you're looking for,you could do this:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();  
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){  
 map.put(array[i], new Integer(map.get(array[i]).intValue() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for continuous regions, you can use looping since the order matters.

```
List<List<String>> continuous = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> current;
String last = null;
for(String s: array){
    if(!s.equals(last)){
        current = new ArrayList<>();
        continuous.add(current);
    }
    current.add(s);
    last=s;
}
```

In your example, you could use a stream and the grouping by collector since the regions are also unique characters.

```
Map<String, List<String>> grouped = Arrays.stream(array).collect(
                                        Collectors.groupingBy(String::toString)
                                    );
```

If you really need the String[] instead of List, you can use List.toArray.

```
String[] arr_version = grouped.get("0").toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map with string as index and integer as value.
Then you can loop this array and assign the values of array as index of the map and keep increasing the integer value.

For example, you can add these lines inside the loop, and you will have a map:

```
Map<String, Integer> myCharMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
myCharMap.put(array[index], new Integer(myCharMap.get(array[index]).intValue()+1));
```